# How to insert images after some specific functions in Sphinx docs?

Tags: python, image, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

I'm new to Sphinx. I generated `.rst` files using autodoc. The following is the `.rst` file for one of the modules:

```
Building things
=====================

Actions
----------------------------------

.. automodule:: acat.build.actions
    :members: func1, func2, func3
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

Patterns
----------------------------------

.. automodule:: acat.build.patterns
    :members: func4, func5
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

Orderings
----------------------------------

.. automodule:: acat.build.orderings
    :members: func6
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Now I want to insert images after `func1`, `func3` and `func5`, I know the image can be embedded by

```
.. image:: func1_example.png
```

But where should I put these lines to make the images appear right under the corresponding functions?

Comment: If you put that directive in the function's docstring, is it placed where you want?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want these image-related lines appear in the docstring of my source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have 1 module with 2 functions and 3 docstrings, e.g:

`acat.build.actions.py`

```
"""
The module docstring.
"""

def func1():
"""
Docstring of func1.
"""


def func2():
"""
Docstring of func2.
"""
```

In order to insert the image exactly where you want it you have to declare the image in the exact position in the `.rst` file. So you would write the `acat.build.actions.rst` like this:

```
Building things
=====================

Actions
----------------------------------

.. automodule:: acat.build.actions
    :members:
    :exclude-members: func1
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
    
    .. autofunction:: func1
        
        You can write some text here.
        
        .. image:: func1_example.png
```

You exclude `func1` explicitly from the module using the `:exclude-members: func1` option
because you want to include the image right underneath it. This allows you to write the documentation of `func1` in a customized way, the [`.. autofunction::` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autofunction) will extract the docstring of `func1` from the `.py` file but you are able to write the reStructuredText you want inside it. If you want to do this for more functions apply the same technique.